# how to get value of these inputs using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it possible to find an input by it's closest element?
real code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="rocket-form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Person Contacts</legend>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="rocket-label-element no-height">
            <dt id="id-label">&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd id="id-element">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" readonly="readonly" id="id">
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="rocket-label-element no-height"><dt id="vendor_id-label">&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd id="vendor_id-element">
                <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id" value="" readonly="readonly" id="vendor_id">
            </dd>
        </div>
        <div class="rocket-label-element">
            <div id="firstname-label">
                <label for="firstname" class="rocket-label optional">First name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rocket-element">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="any first name" maxlength="64" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rocket-label-element">
            <div id="lastname-label">
                <label for="lastname" class="rocket-label optional">Last name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rocket-element">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="any last name" maxlength="64" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rocket-label-element">
            <div id="phone-label">
                <label for="phone" class="rocket-label optional">Phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rocket-element">
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="0123456789" maxlength="32" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rocket-label-element">
            <div id="email-label">
                <label for="email" class="rocket-label optional">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rocket-element">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="name@someMail.com" maxlength="128" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have this form, and I want to get the value of the inputs in variables..
I tried to use "vendor_id" in order to use closest() or next() or prev() but no luck..
so, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
var form = $("#vendor_id").closest("form").get();
$("form :input").each(function(){
 var input = $(this);
 var AllInputValues= $(input).val();
 alert (AllInputValues);

});
```

**EDIT**

```
var theVendform = $("#vendor_id").parent().closest("form").get();
                alert(theVendform["0"][3].defaultValue);
                alert(theVendform["0"][4].defaultValue);
                alert(theVendform["0"][5].defaultValue);
                alert(theVendform["0"][6].defaultValue);
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot, but it would be inappropriate to ask how to get them separated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var vendorId = $("#vendor_id").val();
```

to get the value of vendor_id.

Be sure to include the **#** which identifies it as an id.

If you want to get the values of all the inputs, you can use:

```
$("input, select, textarea").each(function(){
    // Get value of inputs
});
```

If you have more than one form, you may use:

```
var formData = $(".rocket-form").closest("form").serialize();
```

Remember you will need to include jQuery with a script tag and you should wrap your code like so:

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

This ensures the page is ready before your JavaScript executes.

Comment: I need to get the values of <input(s) > related to #vendor_id, because I have another 4 forms in the page

Comment: Could you add an id or name?

Comment: unfortunately I can't

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand what you are asking but what about

`$('#vendor_id-element input').val()`

Comment: I need to get the values of <input(s) >

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var inputs = $('form').find('input');
//inputs is the array of your inputs and values can be accessed by:
var value1 = $(inputs[0]).val();

//or you can use for loop or forEach
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = $(inputs[i]).val();
    alert(currentValue);

}
```

Comment: great Idea, but unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: I was thinking about `var elems = $("#vendor_id");;
 var elemsval = elems.parent().parent().nextAll('input').first().val();`  but no luck

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors? The code seems to be working fine in my part. btw, I've updated the code

Comment: great, thanks a lot, but it would be inappropriate to ask how to get them separated?

Comment: this code will get me all forms in the file, right?

Comment: yes. it would be better if you give the form you want an id and just use that as a selector for the form you want to get

Answer (score 0):

You a class  in all your inputs where you want to get value, and do de following js

```
  Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelector('.your-input-class')).forEach(function(el){
       Console.log(el.value);
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't add classes